# Sending a list of doubles as strings to the database

Tags: c#

Just quite confused with the piece of code below.

I have class like below

```
public class Counter
{       
    public Double NormalCounter { get; set; }
    public Double SATCounter { get; set; }
    public Double SUNCounter { get; set; }
   
}
```

in my main class i have method to do some calculation to fill the counter

```
Counter CountHrs = GetBookedHours(resourceBkg, PrevEvent);
var lstExpResult = new List<string> {CountHrs.NormalCounter.ToString(),
                                     CountHrs.SATCounter.ToString(), 
                                     CountHrs.SUNCounter.ToString()};
UpdateBooking(bookingSesid, lstExpResult);
```

Just assume i have the value like below in the counter

> NormalCounter =4
>
> SATCounter=10
>
> SUNCounter=6

am trying to add in to string list and update the database.is that the right way to do ? or any other options i have please.

my update booking method is below to give clear idea.

```
 public static bool UpdateBooking(string BookingSesid,List<string>HoursByRate)
    {
         SchedwinEntities db = new SchedwinEntities();
         string value = string.Empty;
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
             string str = " ";
             if (i < HoursByRate.Count())
             {
                 str = HoursByRate[i];
                 value += str + ((char)13).ToString() + ((char)10).ToString();
             }
         }
            var query = 
            from SEVTs in db.SEVTs
            where
            SEVTs.SESID.Trim() == BookingSesid//SESID
            select SEVTs;
        foreach (var SEVTs in query)
        {
            SEVTs.USER3 = value;//value
        }
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (UpdateException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The c++ in me also says you should use an integer type if you have counters, cuz doubles aren't guaranteed to stay on exact values, but again, we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Am not sure why i got negative for this question ?

Comment: My guess is because the first iteration of the question was unclear. (I didn't downvote you, it's just my guess).

Comment: any way thanks a lot rein and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than passing a list of strings that represent `double`s, you should pass a list of key-value pairs, construct a parametersized statement from them, and use the list of key-value-pairs to bind parameter values, like this:

```
class SqlParamBinding {
    string Name {get;set;}
    object Value {get;set;} 
}
var lstExpResult = new List<SqlParamBinding> {
    new SqlParamBinding { Name = "NormalCounter", Value = CountHrs.NormalCounter}
,   new SqlParamBinding { Name = "SATCounter", Value = CountHrs.SATCounter}
,   new SqlParamBinding { Name = "SUNCounter", Value = CountHrs.SUNCounter}
};
UpdateBooking(bookingSesid, lstExpResult);
```

Now that `lstExpResult` separates names from values, your `UpdateBooking` code could format the SQL expression as

```
WHERE NormalCounter=@NormalCounter AND SATCounter=@SATCounter AND ...
```

and then bind `@NormalCounter`, `@SATCounter`, and `@SUNCounter` to the values passed in the `lstExpResult` list.

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to list of Counter classes then have List instead of List. Looks like you might be having bunch of Counter objects that might be getting updated or sent to the database.

```
    Counter c = new Counter();
    c. NormalCounter = 4
    c.SATCounter = 10
    c.SunCounter = 10

    List<Counter> listCounter = new List<Counter>
    listCounter.Add(c);
```

Code is more maintainable and readable.

If you are sending one object at a time, then no need of list at all. You can pass in the counter object to your UpdateMethod and parse it while updating the database.

Comment: thanks @opensourcelover, if you seen my update method will take string list,that's why am trying the option above otherwise your's is the easiest and neat one.